# Kubernetes cert manager dns01 challenge for dnsmadeeasy

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager, acme

I have deployed my application in Kubernetes. I have configured the cert manager and issuers to generate an ssl certificate for the specificsubdomain. It works fine. Now I want to generate the wildcard SSL certificate. For wildcard, ACME/letsencrypt use the dns01 challenge. My DNS provider is not on the list of supported DNS providers. My domain is hosted in dnsmadeeasy. How to complete the dns01 challenge to get an ssl certificate?

Comment: If your dns provider is not listed then you will have to use the [webhook](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/webhook/). You will find more webhook solvers [here](https://github.com/topics/cert-manager-webhook).

Comment: my dns provider is not available in webhook solvers list.

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/438) github issue thread and [this](https://github.com/go-acme/lego) repo. There is implementation for _dnsmadeeasy_ inside it.

Comment: https://go-acme.github.io/lego/dns/dnsmadeeasy/ Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @AkshayGopani, does the comment from the sam thomas helped you?

Comment: No. Things share by Thomas is I know. I looking for complete implementation.

Comment: Did you try [`dnsmadeeasy-webhook` solution](https://github.com/k8s-at-home/charts/tree/master/charts/stable/dnsmadeeasy-webhook)?

Comment: nope i will try. @MikolajS.

Comment: Hi @Akshay Gopani, any news?